# Change the default shell to run .sh files

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I am running quite a few installation scripts in `.sh` files. I noticed that if I simply run `./my_script.sh`, they will report `[[: not found` unless I explicitly specify `bash ./my_script.sh`. Google search suggests that the default is equivalent to `sh ./my_script.sh` and that is why this happened.

Now I have a bunch of scripts written  by someone else assuming that I use `bash` and called quite a few `.sh` files. I can go in the scripts and explicitly add `bash` in front of them; but would there be a way to associate `.sh` files with bash by default?

Note: I am using bash already - I can see the result of `echo $0` is `bash`.

Shawn

Answer (score 4):

As the very first line of your scripts add in a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line for the interpreter.  That way you don't have to specify the shell before you run the script.

Examples:

For `bash` add in

```
#!/bin/bash
```

For `sh` add in

```
#!/bin/sh
```

etc.

With Linux file extensions are ignored to tell the kernel what type of file it is.  Instead it is best to add it as the very first line in the script to tell it what it is.  As a test here is the same file but with a different interpreter as the first line.

```
~$ file a.txt
a.txt: ASCII text
~$ cat a.txt

11
22
33
44
55
11
```

Now I will add a shebang line as outlined above as the very first line in that file and run the test again:

```
~$ file a.txt
a.txt: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
~$ cat a.txt
#!/bin/bash
11
22
33
44
55
11
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Terrance! I appreciate it and that did help. My challenge is that I am pulling a huge repo where there are many (> 10) .sh files... I can go edit one by one, but I was wondering whether there would be a global setting. Do you happen to know?

Comment: @ShawnWang Not that I am aware of.  I did update that Linux pretty much ignores file extensions so there would be no way in the shell to tell it that file opens that way.  You can do it in the file browsers though, but that can be more of a pain to set up especially for scripts.  Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/file-extensions-for-unix-shell-scripts

Comment: Ah thank you! I just also found out that my scripts has unzipping and `sh` files can come up of the zip files.... Almost impossible to change one by one then. I'll probably give up not soon after... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ShawnWang You could use `sed` to add the line as the very first line in a file.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99351/111521  It could be done via `sed -i '1i #!/bin/bash' filename.sh`  It also accept wildcards as well `sed -i '1i #!/bin/bash' *.sh` but make sure that you are in the same folder as all the .sh files.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in other answers, the files you downloaded are not associated with a particular shell interpreter by their `.sh` extension, but by their `#!/bin/sh` "shebang".

Since early days, Ubuntu has used the Almquist `dash` shell to provide `/bin/sh` as discussed here:

- [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Other systems (particularly legacy Linux systems) may assume that `/bin/sh` is provided by `bash` - which is why you are seeing the errors that you are. Although I wouldn't recommend it, the literal answer to your question *"would there be a way to associate .sh files with bash by default"* is given in the above link [My production system has broken and I just want to get it back up!](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#My_production_system_has_broken_and_I_just_want_to_get_it_back_up.21) i.e.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

but please note the associated warning:

> **Beware that this is a more invasive change, will undo boot speed
>   benefits, and there is even an outside chance that there are a few
>   scripts that now depend on some feature of dash that bash does not
>   provide!**